# While navigating between screens, how to animate a screen from bottom-to-top in react native in Android?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

When navigating between screens change the animation to animate from bottom-to-top rather than right to left.

```
<Stack.Screen
        name="OfferDetails"
        options={{headerShown: false, presentation: 'modal',}}
        component={OfferDetails}
      />
```

Tried this according to react navigation docs. Not working on android.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Import `Animated` from react-native.

```
import { View, Animated } from 'react-native';
```

Step 2 : Define below given function in your navigator file.

```
const moveBottomToTop = ({ current, next, inverted, layouts: { screen } }) => {
  const progress = Animated.add(
    current.progress.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [0, 1],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    }),
    next
      ? next.progress.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0, 1],
          extrapolate: 'clamp',
        })
      : 0,
  );

  return {
    cardStyle: {
      transform: [
        {
          translateY: Animated.multiply(
            progress.interpolate({
              inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
              outputRange: [
                screen.width, // Focused, but offscreen in the beginning
                0, // Fully focused
                screen.width * -0.3, // Fully unfocused
              ],
              extrapolate: 'clamp',
            }),
            inverted,
          ),
        },
      ],
    },
  };
};
```

Step 3 : Use the above mentioned function likewise where you define your screen.

```
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Screen_NAME"
        component={ScreenComponent}
        options={{
          headerShown: false, //all upto you
          cardStyleInterpolator: moveBottomToTop,
        }}
      />
```